# How can I make a 'wscript' file that compiles a c file with one set of cxxflags, and a cpp with a different set of cxxflags

Tags: c++, windows, node.js

I am trying to compile a NodeJS native module, using two files: 1 .c file and 1 .cpp file. Here's what my 'wscript' file looks like:

```
def set_options(opt):
  opt.tool_options("compiler_cxx")

def configure(conf):
  conf.check_tool("compiler_cxx")
  conf.check_tool("node_addon")

def build(bld):
  obj = bld.new_task_gen("cxx")
  obj.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall", "-x", "objective-c"]
  obj.source = "c-file.c"
  obj = bld.new_task_gen("cxx", "shlib", "node_addon")
  obj.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall"]
  obj.target = "binding"
  obj.source = "cpp-file.cc"
```

This builds me a `binding.node` file which I can then partially use in Node, but as soon as I call the function that is located in the C file (the one compiled first in the wscript above), Node crashes with something like:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __Z9getSomethingv
  Referenced from: /Users/nrajlich/test/build/default/binding.node
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

This leads me to believe that the first file isn't being included in the linking phase, but I'm just not sure how I'm supposed to add it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what I was originally trying to do is possible with `waf`.

In this case, I was trying to compile C++ and Obj-C code together and use them together. Originally I had the Obj-C code in the `.c` files and the C++ code in the `.cc` files, and was trying to pass different flags for the different file types.

Since then, I've learned that Obj-C and C++ may be combined in the same file! And I just needed to add an `-ObjC++` flag to `g++`. This was easily done in `waf`, and also allowed to to consolidate all the needed stuff into a single file. Everything works great from there.

So I was able to solve what I originally was trying to do, however the original question I asked I don't believe is possible to do with `waf`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
def set_options(opt):
  opt.tool_options("compiler_cxx")

def configure(conf):
  conf.check_tool("compiler_cxx")
  conf.check_tool("node_addon")

def build(bld):
  obj = bld.new_task_gen("cxx", "shlib", "node_addon")
  obj.cxxflags = ["-g", "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64", "-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE", "-Wall"]
  obj.target = "binding"
  obj.source = """
    cpp-file.cc
    c-file.c
  """
```

That's how you should do this.